# Using data from 2 different databases in a LightSwitch application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I need to write a LightSwitch application, which displays a grid with data from 2 different tables, which are located in 2 different databases.

There is table `A` with column `BankId` in one database and table `B` with columns `BankId` and `BankName`. I need to display `BankName` as well as some data from table `A`.

Is it possible to implement this in LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Create a database view in the one database that joins table A to the table B in the other database and import that view as part of your external database datasource

2) Create a RIA domain service datasource that internally does the join in the same way as 1 above. There are lots of articles on the internet about creating RIA services for LightSwitch.

Options 1 is probably the quickest.